# missing terminating ' character (C, version 13, Xcode + Terminal)

Tags: c, syntax

I'm just getting into C and this is the code I'm trying to get the compiler to run using gcc:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

main()

{

printf("hello, world\n");

}
```

Every time I type `gcc helloworld.c` (`helloworld.c` is the name of the source file), the following error message appears:

```
helloworld.c:1:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf2580
^
helloworld.c:13:9: warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
printf(\'93hello, \'93);\
        ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

I tried switching to single quotation and putting quotation marks around every single character but nothing worked. Does anyone have any ideas what's wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Where exactly do you get that error message? Did you copy your code from some text program like Word or similar? These programs add strange things to text files.

Comment: I'm compiling/gcc-ing the source file on terminal. Supposedly a .out executable is created if it works?  I did it on terminal and that's where the message popped up. The code I wrote using visual studio editor.

Comment: Please show the command you use for compiling and also include the exact error message into your question.

Comment: Command: gcc helloworld.c; Exact error message: helloworld.c:1:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf2580
^
helloworld.c:13:9: warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
printf(\'93hello, \'93);\
        ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.

Comment: Please add this to your question. You can use the "edit" button below your question for this purpose.

Comment: `{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf2580` Did you save your code in Rich Text Format? That's a no go. You must use a plain text editor without any fancy documents formats.

Comment: Ooooh, maybe that's it, I'll give it another go without any of that. Thanks for being patient with me!

Comment: Whatever program you used, don't touch code files with that again. ;) Use a text editor. There are plenty of them.

Comment: This will probably be the most important lesson I'll ever learn haha Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing the program out by hand. If you copy-pasted it from somewhere, you might have put some weird invisible characters and formatting stuff. I copy-pasted the code from your example and it worked just fine. Compiled successfully with GCC:

`gcc input.c -o program`